# C++ Making A Game in the win32 console

Tags: c++, winapi

So my question is kind of a tricky one, at least for me. I am trying to make a game in C++ for the fun of it and basically I what it to be like flappy bird where the bird doesn't ever move but the map behind the bird always is moving from right to left. Basically what I have done so far is created a little grid 5 spaces down and 80 spaces across. I have basically drawn the underscore character _ on the bottom of the map at the 5 spaces from the top and the player is an "O" three spaces from the left. The trouble is getting the 4 spaces above the the 5th space in the height to move but at the same time not moving the the player "O". Here Is my code and a sketch of what happens so far. I'm sorry this is really hard to explain for me. I really tried my best. The problem is I don't really understand it all that well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
bool gameOver;


// Global variables
const int WIDTH = 80;
const int HEIGHT = 5;
int x, y;
int speedX;
int percentX;
int someArray[100];
string anotherArray[100];
enum eKeys { STOP = 0, SPACE};
int gameSpeed;
eKeys key;
// Function declarations
void input() {
    if (_kbhit()) {
        switch (_getch()){
        case ' ': 
            key = SPACE;
            break;
        }
    }
}
void draw() {

    for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
            if (j < 4) {
                std::cout << " ";
                if (WIDTH == 20) {
                    _sleep(10);
                }
            } 
            if(j == 4){
                anotherArray[i] = "_";
                std::cout << anotherArray[i];

            }
            if (j== 3 && i == 3) {
                std::cout << "O";
            }
            if (j == 3 && i == 140) {

            }


        }
    }
}
void setup() {
    gameOver = false;
    key = STOP;
    x = 3;
    y = 2;
}
void logic() {
    switch (key) {
    case SPACE:

        break;
    }
}
int main()
{
    //  Your code goes here
    setup();
    //while(gameOver == false){
        draw();
        input();
        logic();
    //}

    //  Make sure we place the end message on a new line
    std::cout << endl;

    //  The following is system dependent.  It will only work on Windows
    std::system("PAUSE");

    /* 
    // A non-system dependent method is below
    cout << "Press any key to continue";
    cin.get();
    */
    return 0;
}
```

this code produces this output in console....
"this is the top of the console"

O

---

press any key to continue...

what I want is for everything above the "_____" to be moving from right to left without the player moving. Except when you press space to jump then the y coordinate of the "O" will change. Also I know this would be done better in a class probably but I haven't gotten that far in my book and my class for c++ is just now starting functions so It would be best to stay away from that for now.

Comment: You didn't ask an actual question and this is way too broad anyway. Also I'm not sure what exactly you mean by *"better in a class"*

Comment: I mean better done using classes. Like if I did this in java or swift I'd probably create a class called player that had struct in it called Point which had x and y.  I'm just saying that there is better ways to do what I am doing here (Probably) and I want to know how to do it with just functions.

Comment: I don't feel it's to broad. I am basically asking about a concept that applies to any game that moves from right to left. This one is more specific to c++ but I could most likely implement the same answer in a different programming language. Maybe you don't understand the question very well. @unholysheep

Comment: How can I not understand the question when you didn't ask one? "How do I do this?" is not a question suited for SO. Also this isn't really game specific. And you could just clear the entire console and then "redraw" your console output

Comment: I'm trying to do this without the flickering.

Comment: What would you categorize this under then? I seem to have read the policies on SO and have understood clearly that this meets the standards and reputation of any other question on this website. I may not know how to word it better, but my writing skills are below par. It is also 4am where I am so it is hard to think. I am sorry that I have seem to upset you. What tires me even more is that instead of giving me constructive criticism or telling me what I am doing wrong. You are just stating that I am doing something wrong. This helps no one and frustrates everyone reading.

Comment: You won't get there with standard I/O streams and functions, these are designed for simple text output. There *will* be flickering as you clear the terminal and reprint everything. You should instead either use [system-specific terminal commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx), or abstract them behind a cross-platform library such as [ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/).

Comment: @devin: perhaps it is time to take a step back then and get some sleep. Rest brings perspective.

Answer (score 2):

If I have correctly understood, you want to make an ASCII art game on a windows console using C++ level io and conio.h functions. I am sorry but you are at a road end:

- C++ level (iostreams and C stdio or posix functions) are intended to output text data in a sequential manner, so no absolute positionning on screen is available
- conio.h only contains some functions that were used in the times of MS/DOS to do simple i/o operations on keyboard or screen -> no absolute positionning either

In the old MS/DOS days, the screen memory used to be directly accessible at a well known address and game (or application) developpers made use of that to bypass the normal IO functions when special effects were required. Unsure whether the console emulation supports it and I urge you not to use it.

The correct way is now to use the [Console functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of WINAPI. They are used under the hood by the conio emulation and by the normal io functions, but offer all you need for a game, absolute positionning and even the possibility to read and write arbitrary zone of the screen through `ReadConsoleOutput` and `WriteConsoleOutput`

In parallel, you can use `ReadConsoleInput` to get input events from the keyboard.

Of course you have no longer any compatibility with a non Windows platform, but as you already used conio, I assume that portability is not a concern here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about efficiency here.

Store the background in an 80 x 25 array. Then scroll it left on every move, simply by going through it brute force. Copy to another buffer, overlay with the sprites, then write the whole thing out to the screen.

Don't use cout. Use the conio printat() functions.